# Duplicate sources in Ubuntu 14.10's APT files, are they OK?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, repository

So I was preparing to upgrade to ubuntu 15.04 and I was going through and cleaning things up and this is one of things that stood out to me.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/p_conrad:/coins/xUbuntu_14.10/  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.opensuse.org_repositories_home:_p%5fconrad:_coins_xUbuntu%5f14.10_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Now updating with `sudo apt-get update` did nothing, so I went into vim to try to see if I could remove the referrals. I didn't spot anything, but here is the contents of directory.

```
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_partner_binary-amd64_Packages                         security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_restricted_source_Sources
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_partner_binary-i386_Packages                          security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_partner_i18n_Translation-en                           security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_partner_source_Sources                                security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                                               security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_universe_source_Sources
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                                           us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_partner_binary-amd64_Packages                          us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_partner_binary-i386_Packages                           us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_partner_i18n_Translation-en                            us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_main_source_Sources
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_partner_source_Sources                                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_Release                                                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_Release.gpg                                            us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en

download.opensuse.org_repositories_home:_p%5fconrad:_coins_xUbuntu%5f14.10_Packages             us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_multiverse_source_Sources
download.opensuse.org_repositories_home:_p%5fconrad:_coins_xUbuntu%5f14.10_Release              us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_Release
download.opensuse.org_repositories_home:_p%5fconrad:_coins_xUbuntu%5f14.10_Release.gpg          us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_Release.gpg
```

Now this is what I think I should be looking for but this doesn't look like it has the duplicates.

```
download.videolan.org_pub_debian_stable_Packages                                                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
download.videolan.org_pub_debian_stable_Release                                                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
download.videolan.org_pub_debian_stable_Release.gpg                                             us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
download.videolan.org_pub_debian_stable_Sources                                                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_restricted_source_Sources

extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages                                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages                                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages
extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_source_Sources                                       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en
extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                                                   us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-backports_universe_source_Sources
extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                                               us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages

liveusb.info_multisystem_depot_dists_all_main_binary-amd64_Packages                             us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages
liveusb.info_multisystem_depot_dists_all_main_binary-i386_Packages                              us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en
liveusb.info_multisystem_depot_dists_all_Release                                                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_source_Sources
liveusb.info_multisystem_depot_dists_all_Release.gpg                                            us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages

lock                                                                                            us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
partial                                                                                         us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en

ppa.launchpad.net_i-nex-development-team_stable_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages  us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_multiverse_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_i-nex-development-team_stable_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages   us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release
ppa.launchpad.net_i-nex-development-team_stable_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                     us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg
ppa.launchpad.net_i-nex-development-team_stable_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages          us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages           us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en            us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_restricted_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                             us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                         us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_universe_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_next-backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages     us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_universe_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_next-backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages      us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_universe_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_next-backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_next-backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                        us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_kubuntu-ppa_next-backports_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                    us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_n-muench_vlc_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages                   us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_main_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_n-muench_vlc_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages                    us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_n-muench_vlc_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en                     us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_n-muench_vlc_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                                      us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_n-muench_vlc_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                                  us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_multiverse_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_noobslab_indicators_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages            us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_Release
ppa.launchpad.net_noobslab_indicators_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages             us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_Release.gpg
ppa.launchpad.net_noobslab_indicators_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                               us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_noobslab_indicators_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                           us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_otto-kesselgulasch_gimp_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages        us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_otto-kesselgulasch_gimp_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages         us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_restricted_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_otto-kesselgulasch_gimp_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en          us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_otto-kesselgulasch_gimp_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                           us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_otto-kesselgulasch_gimp_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_spring_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages                     us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-updates_universe_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_spring_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages                      us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_spring_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en                       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_spring_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                                        us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_spring_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                                    us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_main_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-wine_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-wine_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-wine_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en                  us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-wine_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                                   us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_multiverse_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-wine_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                               us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_Release
ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_tor-browser_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages        us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_Release.gpg
ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_tor-browser_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages         us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_tor-browser_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en          us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_tor-browser_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                           us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_tor-browser_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_restricted_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_wfg_0ad_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages                        us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_wfg_0ad_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages                         us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_wfg_0ad_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en                          us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_wfg_0ad_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                                           us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-backports_universe_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_wfg_0ad_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                                       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_main_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_xorg-edgers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_main_binary-i386_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_xorg-edgers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-i386_Packages                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_main_i18n_Translation-en
ppa.launchpad.net_xorg-edgers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_i18n_Translation-en                  us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_main_source_Sources
ppa.launchpad.net_xorg-edgers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release                                   us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages
ppa.launchpad.net_xorg-edgers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_utopic_Release.gpg                               us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages

security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages                     us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_main_binary-i386_Packages                      us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_multiverse_source_Sources
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_main_i18n_Translation-en                       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_Release
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_main_source_Sources                            us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_Release.gpg
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages               us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_multiverse_source_Sources                      us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_restricted_source_Sources
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_Release                                        us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_Release.gpg                                    us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_universe_binary-i386_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages               us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_universe_i18n_Translation-en
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_universe_source_Sources
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_restricted_i18n_Translation-en                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_restricted_source_Sources                      us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages                  us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_main_source_Sources
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en                   us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_universe_source_Sources                        us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages                      us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_main_binary-i386_Packages                       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_multiverse_source_Sources
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_main_i18n_Translation-en                        us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_Release
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_main_source_Sources                             us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_Release.gpg
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en                  us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_multiverse_source_Sources                       us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_restricted_source_Sources
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_Release                                         us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_Release.gpg                                     us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages                us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages                 us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_universe_source_Sources
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
```

Now, I installed this: `sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server`
from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/583279/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages-while-installing-nfs-s

Comment: // , Did this occur *after* you responded to the upgrade prompt, or *before*? It might affect the sorts of answers that work best.

Comment: // , Also, in "Now updating with sudo apt-get update did nothing, so I went into vim to try to see if I could remove the referrals. I didn't spot anything, but here is the contents of directory.", to which directory do you refer, Jay?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate `source.list` entries aren't a big problem, just a small performance hit.

The message is misleading: `apt-get update` alone won't eliminate duplicate entries. You need to edit the `source.list` files: `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Look for entries for the repository mentioned in the error message and remove one of the duplicates. *Then* run `apt-get update`.

Comment: Is there a less error-prone way to do this than directly editing the core configuration file for software sources as root?

Comment: @basanese There may be GUIs for that, but how is editing the source files error-prone?

Comment: For the same reason that anything starting with `sudo vi` is error prone. Humans have been known to accidentally delete files, make spelling errors, paste something twice and forget it, delete more lines (`dd`) than needed, etc. Well, *other* humans. Surely not @basanese or @Gilles.

Answer (score 0):

I would start out by manually trying the instructions here: [How do I add a line to my /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197564/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-my-etc-apt-sources-list)

Here's how I edited mine:

```
$ ls /etc/apt 
apt.conf.d  preferences  preferences.d  sources.list  sources.list.d sources.list.save  trustdb.gpg  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg~  trusted.gpg.d
$ vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

There's further information here: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Once you have a feel for how that works, I would try using the software here to generate a replacement `sources.list` file: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Solving a duplicate sources.list entry is as simple as a few command lines. I am hesitant to just add to the usual map of system issues to arcane command lines, or even to make a more specific example, until I have more information about what Jay's tried. The real problem here is bigger than a mere duplicate sources.list entry. If an edit to sources.list doesn't solve the problem, it may be time to look at sources.list.d, or find out how the addition to the sources file is even happening, slm. However, I agree with you, in general! Perhaps you have some ideas?

Comment: Lots of ideas but waiting for the OP to come back and give us more info. I edited the Q as much as I could but we need more guidance. I appreciate your trying to help the OP and certainly did not mean anything snarky or anything with that comment, only that links should be passed through comments, or their contents should be paraphrased here.